# Rendering fails with `unCaught (in promise) fetchedUsers.map is not a function` Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mapping

Using useSWR to retrieve data from an endpoint and trying to render all data returned, but I am getting the error:

```
unCaught (in promise) fetchedUsers.map is not a function
uncaught TypeError: fetchedUsers.map is not a function
```

**Here's the code:**

```
const [shouldFetch,setShouldFetch] = useState(false)
const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);
    const { data, error } = useSWR(shouldFetch ? "http://localhost:5000/users": null, fetcher);
    )
const isError = error;
const fetchedUsers = data;
```

**Conditional fetching is implemented onclick:**

```
            <Box>
            <Button
              onClick={() => setShouldFetch(true)}
            >
              View User
            </Button>
          </Box>
```

**The rendering is handled here:**

```
             <Typography
              >
                fetchedUsers? fetchedUsers.map((item) => <>{item}</> : Students Portal
              </Typography>
```

This is what the expected response looks like, but I want a dynamic rendering implementation that can render whatever the data looks like. How can I implement that?

```
   {
        "name": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "age": "10"
                "features":[]
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "age": "11",
            }
        ],
        "id": "71"
    }
```

Comment: change  `onClick= setShouldFetch(true)` to `onClick={()=>  setShouldFetch(true)}`

Comment: @monim I'm getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to call `fetchedUsers.name?map` and not `fetchedUsers.map((item)`

```
fetchedUsers.name?map((item)
```